# Titan and Cassandra Truncating Long Strings When Persisting Graph

Tags: cassandra, titan, gremlin

When creating a graph, for example:

```
TitanGraph graph =  TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties");
Vertex v = graph.addVertex()
v.property("Value", "very very very very very very very very vey long string");
graph.tx().commit();
```

I find that titan is truncating the string to only 20 characters when committing. I am using the standard configuration as defined [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/cassandra.html). Is there some additional configuration I am missing ?

Comment: FYI, the commit syntax in Titan 1.0 is `graph.tx().commit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is that you are getting the result of `VertexProperty.toString()` rather than getting the value with `VertexProperty.value()`. Here is a Gremlin Console session to demonstrate the difference:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.build().set('storage.backend','cassandra').set('storage.cassandra.keyspace','fido').open()
==>standardtitangraph[cassandra:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> v = graph.addVertex() // create a vertex
==>v[4256]
gremlin> v.property('value', 'very very very very very very very very vey long string') // set a property
==>vp[value->very very very very ]
gremlin> v.property('value').getClass() // check the class on the property
==>class com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.StandardVertexProperty
gremlin> v.property('value').toString() // vertex property object as a string
==>vp[value->very very very very ]
gremlin> v.property('value').value().getClass() // check the class of the value of the vertex property
==>class java.lang.String
gremlin> v.property('value').value() // get the value of the vertex property (explicit syntax)
==>very very very very very very very very vey long string
gremlin> v.values('value').next().getClass() // check the class of the value of the vertex property
==>class java.lang.String
gremlin> v.values('value').next() // get the value of the vertex property (simpler syntax)
==>very very very very very very very very vey long string
```

There is some discussion about [vertex properties](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#vertex-properties) worth reading in the TinkerPop3 documentation.